# Есть название потока в виде текста. Как его запустить?

Tags: java

Как запустить поток "thread", если мне известно только его имя?

```
public class thread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}
String AAA = "thread"; // Имя потока
new Thread(Class.forName(AAA)).start(); // <-- Вопрос по этой строке
```

Comment: Смотрите сюда: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html или лучше сюда http://stackoverflow.com/a/6094602/1646082

Comment: Вам не должно такого хотеться, по идее. Java — язык со статической типизацией, в ней такие штуки обычно не нужны. Какая ваша _реальная_ задача? Для чего вам это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания потока исполнения в Java, необходимо либо реализовать интерфейс Runnable либо расширить класс Thread. В вашем случае класс thread реализует интерфейс Runnable, соответственно Вам необходимо создать экземпляр этого класса thread t = new thread();
После создания класса, реализующего интерфейс Runnable, в этом классе следует получить экземпляр объекта типа Thread. Для этой цели в классе Thread определен ряд конструкторов. Тот конструктор, который должен использоваться в данном случае, выглядит в общей форме следующим образом: Thread (Runnable вашОбьект), после его необходимо запустить методом start().

пример

```
public class ThreadMY implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
             System.out.println(" " + i);
    } 
}

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadMY t = new ThreadMY();
        new Thread(t).start();
    }
}
```

Если у Вас, есть только название класса а самого класса нет, тогда шансов его запустить у Вас нет. Если есть сам файл класса (thread.class) то все делается как написано ваше. Если вы хотите создать экземпляр класса через String тогда

```
try {
   ThreadMY t = (ThreadMY)Class.forName("имяПАКЕТА.ThreadMY").newInstance();
   new Thread( t ).start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.print(ex);
}
```

Ваш код

```
String AAA = "thread";
try {
   thread t = (thread)Class.forName(AAA).newInstance();
   new Thread( t ).start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.print(ex);
}
```

Для заметки

```
 // метод класса Class
 Object newInstance() //Возвращает новый экземпляр класса.
```

Использует конструктор по умолчанию (т.е. конструктор без параметров).Если в классе конструктор по умолчанию отсутствует, генерируется исключение. Незабываем ловить исключения.
   Например:

```
String s = "java.util.Date";
Object m = Class.forName(s).newInstance();
```

Если при создании объекта на основе имени класса нужно передать конструктору какие-либо параметры, использовать приведенные выше выражения нельзя. Вместо этого нужно применять метод newInstance() класса Constructor.

```
 // метод класса Constructor
 Object newInstance(Object[] args)
```

Создает новый экземпляр класса «args»-Параметры, передаваемые конструктору. Подробнее о применении параметров читайте в разделе, посвященном рефлексии.

Comment: Немножко не то, но всё равно Спасибо от души. Кое-что тут пригодилось.